# Using drools in Web Application

Tags: java, web-applications, drools

I am trying to use drools in web application (I clicked in NetBeans new Project -> Maven -> Web Application and chose GlassFish 4.1 server).

I tried exact same code in Maven Java Project (not Web App) and it works, however in web app, it does nothing. Here is the code:

```
public static final String pathDrl = "res/rules.drl";

public File fireRules() throws FileNotFoundException {
    KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieFileSystem kfs = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pathDrl);
    kfs.write(pathDrl, kieServices.getResources().newInputStreamResource(fis));
    KieBuilder kieBuilder = kieServices.newKieBuilder(kfs).buildAll();

    Results results = kieBuilder.getResults();
    if (results.hasMessages(org.kie.api.builder.Message.Level.ERROR)) {
        System.out.println(results.getMessages());
        throw new IllegalStateException("###> Errors in DRL <###");
    }

    KieContainer kieContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(kieServices.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId());
    KieBase kieBase = kieContainer.getKieBase();
    KieSession kSession = kieContainer.newKieSession();     

    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    s.append("a");      

    kSession.insert(s);
    kSession.fireAllRules();  

    System.out.println(s);

    return null;
}
```

Here is the DRL file:

```
rule "rule1"
    when    
        s : StringBuilder()
    then
        s.append("AA");
end
```

Output in MavenJavaProject: "aAA", in web app: "a".

However when I am running server, this warning pops up:

```
Warning:   Could not instantiate service class org.drools.compiler.cdi.KieCDIExtension
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kie/api/runtime/KieContainer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.prepareInstance(ServiceLoader.java:238)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.loadService(ServiceLoader.java:214)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.loadServiceFile(ServiceLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.reload(ServiceLoader.java:153)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.iterator(ServiceLoader.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.weld.DeploymentImpl.getExtensions(DeploymentImpl.java:466)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.processApplication(ApplicationLoaderService.java:406)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLoaderService.postConstruct(ApplicationLoaderService.java:243)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:329)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:377)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:461)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:84)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2258)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1162)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppLibClassLoaderServiceImpl$URLClassFinder.findClass(AppLibClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:168)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 29 more
```

This is how my pom.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SoapServerMaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>SoapServerMaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>SoapServerMaven</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <drools.version>6.2.0.Final</drools.version>
        <jbpm.version>6.2.0.Final</jbpm.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If anybody have any idea why it isn't working, I would really appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: So which jars are present in the WEB-INF/lib of the war that is deployed in the server? I'm kind of expecting the drools-compiler jar to not be there, for whatever reason.

Comment: I don't even have lib directory in there, to be honest this is the first time working with web application and stuff like that. So what is the right course of actions? Should I copy jars from maven repo into WEB-INF/lib dir?

Comment: Oof. Sorry, I'd recommend taking a loooong step back and informing yourself before you dive in this deep, JavaEE is just not that trivial. Please, consider getting a good book. I found "Java EE 7 with GlassFish 4 Application Server" to be pretty friendly for beginners.

Comment: When I am thinking about it, this will probably not be the problem. Because I use in other class third party lib "org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils" and it is working without copying it to some folder in GlassFish.

Comment: My bad, every lib is in war, I can't find them in GlassFish, but in target folder of netbeans project is war with them.

Comment: What drools-related libraries do you see there? Is kie-api-XXX.jar in there? The main difference between Glassfish and your java app is that when running inside Glassfish, Drools realises that it is being executed inside a JEE container and uses some other classes (i.e. KieCDIExtension) that are not part of a regular execution in a JSE environment. Could you please provide the full list of kie-* and drools-* jars you have in your .war?

Comment: @EstebanAliverti I have few drools jars in war: "drools-compiler-6.3.0.Final.jar, drools-core-6.3.0.Final.jar, kie-api-6.3.0.Final.jar, kie-internal-6.3.0.Final.jar". I use org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer in code and import seems fine. I looked into drools-compiler-6.3.0.Final.jar and KieCDIExtension.class is in there.

Comment: The libraries seems to be fine. Could you try deploying your .war in other containers (i.e. wildfly) to see if the problem is strictly related to Glassfish?

Comment: I will, it will just take me some time because of lack of experience.

Comment: @EstebanAliverti Ok, I have tried it with WildFly. No exceptions during deployment, however result is the same, it behaves as no rule was fired. Output: `10:25:19,279 WARN  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule] (default task-9) No files found for KieBase defaultKieBase
10:25:19,280 INFO  [org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieRepositoryImpl] (default task-9) KieModule was added: MemoryKieModule[releaseId=org.default:artifact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
10:25:19,283 INFO  [stdout] (default task-9) a`

Comment: It's working now, I don't know what exactly was wrong, but I changed path to drl like 100x times and now it works.